# How to borrow an immutable view (slice?) to a vector as octets?

Tags: type-conversion, rust

I'm trying to send a vector of 32-bit floats over network using UDP. The `UdpSocket.send_to(buf, dst)` method accepts a slice of 8-bit uints. I'd like to pass it the vector as an `&[u8]`. How do I accomplish this? I didn't find any relevant conversion methods from the API.

No need to care about endianness in this case. Yet.

Comment: The only way for this to make sense would be that a slice of `f32` could be viewed as a slice of `u8` at byte level and the language would guarantee the representation (somehow)... I think that would be better served by first creating a `Vec<u8>` and then convert your `Vec<f32>` to that in whatever way you want.

Comment: Matthieu: That's exactly what I meant. In other words: I want to serialize the floats as bytes. I thought that Rust uses always IEEE floating points, so endianness aside, the byte representation is always the same. Also, I was hoping that I don't need to copy the vector over. In C I can do that – and I presume it's possible in Rust too. But dunno about if you need unsafe block for that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, such operations are inherently unsafe and hence they can't be done without `unsafe` block.

A slice is a pair `(pointer, length)`, and while you can cast a raw pointer to some type as a raw pointer to another type, you also need to tweak the length to keep the resulting slice valid. This can be done like this:

```
use std::raw::Slice;
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let floats: Vec<f32> = vec![0.1, 2.3, 4.5, 6.7];
    let floats: &[f32] = floats.as_slice();

    let raw_floats: Slice<f32> = unsafe { mem::transmute(floats) };
    let raw_bytes: Slice<u8> = Slice {
        data: raw_floats.data as *const u8,
        len: raw_floats.len * mem::size_of::<f32>()
    };

    let bytes: &[u8] = unsafe { mem::transmute(raw_bytes) };

    println!("{}", bytes);
}
```

(try it [here](http://is.gd/yzRxyd))

Most of type annotations above are there for clarity, of course.

You should take extensive care to ensure that the obtained `&[u8]` slice will not outlive its original data owner (the vector in this case). If you only pass this slice down the call stack (your use case - sending the data over the network - seems to be this), then you're okay; if you need to return such slice from a function, you need to take care for lifetimes, though Rust type/lifetime inference is advanced enough to make them almost invisible. For example, a generic method for conversion from `&[T]` to `&[u8]` could look like this:

```
use std::raw::Slice;
use std::mem;

fn view_as_bytes<'a, T: Copy>(items: &'a [T]) -> &'a [u8] {  // '
    let raw_items: Slice<T> = unsafe { mem::transmute(items) };
    let raw_bytes = Slice {
        data: raw_items.data as *const u8,
        len: raw_items.len * mem::size_of::<T>()
    };
    let bytes: &[u8] = unsafe { mem::transmute(raw_bytes) };
    bytes
}

fn main() {
    let floats: Vec<f32> = vec![0.1, 2.3, 4.5, 6.7];
    let bytes = view_as_bytes(floats.as_slice());

    println!("{}", bytes);
}
```

(try it [here](http://is.gd/sDRMOI))

I've added lifetime parameter `'a` for clarity, but it can be omitted safely due to lifetime elision.

If your data is created inside a function, however, you should not return any slices into it from this function. `transmute()` is powerful enough to allow this, but it will only lead to segfault eventually.

Comment: Please consider showing how to properly do the lifetime thing. I'd write an `unsafe fn as_raw_bytes(s: &[f32]) -> &[u8]` relying on the lifetime elision rules. Maybe it's even better idea to be explicit in this case since it's an unsafe function and instead of a compilation error, you'd get a into dangling pointer trouble if the lifetimes are wrong.

Comment: @sellibitze, it seems I was a bit pessimistic. `copy_lifetime` wasn't needed here at all, `transmute` does all the necessary work. I'm updating the answer right now.

Comment: @sellibitze, BTW, there is no reason to mark `as_raw_bytes()` unsafe. You can't violate memory safety with this function when it is used in safe context provided its implementation is bug-free. `as_raw_bytes_mut(...) -> &mut [u8]`, however, would indeed be unsafe (though I don't know why someone would need one).

Comment: I would use `copy_lifetime` to be explicit and show intent. The `transmute` thingy is pretty unsafe and might do something unintended. And the reason why I'd make `as_raw_bytes` unsafe is because the observable behaviour depends on the endianess of the machine. But we could argue about whether this is a misuse of `unsafe` or not. ;)

Comment: @sellibitze, unfortunately, `copy_lifetime` won't work here. I tried to use it first, of course, but it is only defined for sized types, and `[u8]` is not sized. Endianess issue didn't occur to me, you're completely right (though I still think that `unsafe` is not exactly appropriate :))

Comment: And `transmute` is still needed to convert `Slice` to `&[u8]`, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a single float to its representation as bytes, use [`mem::transmute`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html)

```
let floaty_stuff = 234.5f32;
let bytes: [u8, ..4] = unsafe{ std::mem::transmute(floaty_stuff) };
let slice = bytes.as_slice(); // this is &[u8]
```

To do this for a vector, you can just [`.iter().map(|f| mem::transmute::<[u8 ..4], f32>(f).as_slice() )`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.map).